# Django password change

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Why does the following code result in my user being logged out when they enter a new, valid password?

```
@login_required
def change_password(request):
    pass_form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pass_form = PasswordChangeForm(user=request.user, data=request.POST)
        if pass_form.is_valid():
            pass_form.save()
            return render(request,'coursework/profile.html',
                                      {'pass_form' : pass_form,
                                       'pass_msg' : 'Password Updated'})
    return render(request, 'coursework/new_password_form.html',
                              {'form': pass_form})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a security measure implemented by Django, and it is enabled in the default configuration – as soon as a user changes their password, all existing sessions are invalidated. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#session-invalidation-on-password-change

You need to add the following to your view after `pass_form.save()` in order to keep the current session valid:

```
update_session_auth_hash(request, pass_form.user)
```

Answer (score 2):

Django [invalidates sessions when the password is changed](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#session-invalidation-on-password-change). You need to call             `update_session_auth_hash` to prevent this.

Note that you don't have to write your own `change_password` method. Django comes with a [`password_change`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.password_change) method, which takes care of updating the session for you.