# django user profile editing with login_required

Tags: python, django

I have prepared view and form in the aim to edit user profile (name, surname, email and password). The problem is that I am able to change the user profile (password) but after all django redirect to the login view. It looks like that django logout the user after data changes. But why?

```
view.py
@login_required()
def edit_user_view(request):
    template_name = "user_account/user_edit.html"
    form = EditUserForm(request.POST or None, instance=request.user)

    if form.is_valid():
        new_user_data = form.save()
        new_user_data.set_password(form.cleaned_data['new_password_1'])
        new_user_data.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/user_account/user_edit/') 
    return render(request, template_name, {'form': form,
                                       'edit_succes': True})

forms.py
class EditUserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email', 'name', 'surname']

    new_password_1 = forms.CharField(max_length=30, min_length=8)
    new_password_2 = forms.CharField(max_length=30, min_length=8)

user_edit.html
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

From Django documentation on **changing passwords** (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/auth/default/#changing-passwords):

> Changing a user’s password will log out all their sessions if the
>   SessionAuthenticationMiddleware is enabled. See Session invalidation
>   on password change for details.

It's a standard procedure and you will have to delete *SessionAuthenticationMiddleware* from your middleware if you insist on not reloging your users.

Comment: It might be a better idea to call `update_session_auth_hash ` instead of disabling the session authentication middleware (see the answers on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36158486/django-password-change)). That way, other sessions are logged out, but the current session remains logged in.